# TCP Socket in Swift

Tags: sockets, tcp, swift, gcdasyncsocket

I am trying to write a TCP socket client in swift using GCDAsyncSocket, but I am having a lot of problems. In my code I have a NSTextField (called box) and here is my code:
    import Cocoa

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSTextField!

    let bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: AppDelegate.self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        var port:UInt16 = 8090
        if (!bsocket.connectToHost("localhost", onPort: port, error: nil))
        {
            println("Error")
        }
        else
        {
            println("Connecting...")
        }
        var request:String = "Arn.Preg:3302:"
        var data:NSData = request.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
        bsocket.writeData(data, withTimeout: -1.0, tag: 0)
        bsocket.readDataWithTimeout(-1.0, tag: 0)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) 
    {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)
    {
        var response = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        println("Received Response")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + response
    }

    func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host:String, port p:UInt16)
    {
        println("Connected to \(host) on port \(p).")
        box.stringValue = box.stringValue + "\n" + "Connected to \(host) on port \(p)."
    }
}
```

When I run the code, what I want it to do is display the text that the TCP server returns in the text box, but for some reason, the function

```
func socket(socket : GCDAsyncSocket, didReadData data:NSData, withTag tag:UInt16)
```

Never gets run. When I use the telnet command in the terminal to achieve the same result, the server returns this:

```
Marzuk:~ marzukrashid$ telnet localhost 8090
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Arn.TipoSer:XPL0:
```

Then, when I type in "Arn.Preg:3302:", the server returns this:

```
Marzuk:~ marzukrashid$ telnet localhost 8090
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Arn.TipoSer:XPL0:
Arn.Preg:3302:
Arn.Resp:3302=329351:
```

When I type in "Arn.Preg:3302:" the server returns "Arn.Resp:3302=329351:", this is the result I am trying to achieve, I want the NSTextField in my application to display "Arn.Resp:3302=329351:".

My question is why is my code not doing this, and how can I fix my code into doing this.

Thanks.

**Edit:** When I run the program, the NSTextField is empty and the program prints "Connecting..." but it does not print "Connected" or anything else.

Comment: What gets printed out? Do you see "Connecting..." and "Connected"?

Comment: @NateCook "Connecting..." gets printed out but "Connected" does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `self` in your socket initializer isn't what you think -- it's actually a reference to the Type of your AppDelegate. Try moving that initialization inside `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!
    @IBOutlet weak var box: NSTextField!
    var bsocket: GCDAsyncSocket!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?)
    {
        bsocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This sort of did what I intended, when I run it, it now says "Connected to 127.0.0.1 on port 8090." and "Arn.TipoSer:XPL0:" in the NSTextField, and the program prints "Connecting...", "Connected to 127.0.0.1 on port 8090.", and "Received Response", however, I am still not getting "Arn.Resp:3302=329351:"

Comment: That's a whole separate question :)

Comment: Oh, then should I create a separate question?

Comment: Definitely don't sound like an idiot, but I may be the wrong person to help. The problem you were having is that you weren't getting any socket connection information. Now you're connecting, but aren't getting the response you expected. Try figuring out what's wrong, then summarize the new question with everything you know...

Comment: didReadData is only fired if you did call one of the readData functions.